# Making a dynamic level selection textbox

Tags: php, dynamic, textbox

i'm doing a program that allows it's user to choose a number of lessons to create. However, i'm not sure how to implement a for loop to for this dynamic textbox.
This is my first file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="k1levelselect.php" method="post">
How many lessons do you want to create?  <input type="text" name="number" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Type the number of lessons you want to create and click 'Submit'.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my k1levelselect.php , which is after the user type a number and click submit.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Level Buttons</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="button.css" />
<center>
</head>

<body>
<br><img src ="http://i1370.photobucket.com/albums/ag263/Darlene_Fong/makeselection_zps10361dab.jpg"/></br>
<body background="sky.jpg"></body>

<br>

    <?php
        $noOfLesson = $_POST['number'];
        for($noOfLesson=1;$noOfLesson<=10;){
                echo "<td>";
                echo 'k1level1.php' ;
                echo "</div></td>";
        }
        ?>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level1.php"><span>Lesson 1</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level2.php"><span>Lesson 2</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level3.php"><span>Lesson 3</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level4.php"><span>Lesson 4</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level5.php"><span>Lesson 5</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level6.php"><span>Lesson 6</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level7.php"><span>Lesson 7</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level8.php"><span>Lesson 8</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level9.php"><span>Lesson 9</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="k1level10.php"><span>Lesson 10</span></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <a href="kindergardenselect.php"><b>Back</b></a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i edit the for loop such that when the user types in 7, only up to 7 levels will appear?

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=1; $i < $noOfLesson ; $i++) { 
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<a href='k1level$i.php'>Lesson $i</a>" ;
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Loop through each lesson and set the "levels" with your counter variable.

Comment: Did that, but now it literally prints out k1level1-k1level9 instead of showing the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your for loop like this

```
for($noOfLesson = 1; $noOfLesson < 10; $noOfLesson++) {
     echo "<td>";
     echo 'k1level'.$noOfLesson.'.php' ;
     echo "</div></td>";
}
```